Local Tomcat loads https-openssl-nio2-8443 but Eclipse using same Tomcat loads https-jsse-nio-8443 [cannot find Apache Tomcat Native library]
A local Tomcat installation v10.1.28 happily reports:
Apache Tomcat Native library [2.0.8] using APR version [1.7.2] installed. OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024] and using ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-nio2-8443"].
However my local Eclipse IDE running the Local Tomcat server (above) reports:
Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path
and reverts to ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"].
I'd like Eclipse instead to find those Native libraries and allow Tomcat run ["https-openssl-nio2-8443"].
Attempts to point Eclipse to the Tomcat Native libraries (in the server lib directory) failed i.e. pointing Servers targeted runtime to the Tomcat installation.
How should I do this thanks?

Why? I'm not sure its possible as it's expecting a download of Tomcat that doesn't have any native libraries in it, but then what does using the native library let you do that you can't now?

I may be wrong on this - I think Eclipse doesn't download but uses the current locally installed Tomcat instance.  You are absolutely correct in implying that either openssl-nio2 or jsse-nio doesn't make a difference in practical use.  Nevertheless I'd like to employ the openssl implementation (as that's the one in production) and especially would like to know the best way to add the installed Native libraries to Eclipse's java.library.path thus hopefully fixing the error.

When you go to add a Tomcat runtime, it provides you with a button to let it download and unpack it for you. While an installed copy can work, the layout can be a less predictable, especially if installed by a Linux package manager. When Eclipse is launching Tomcat, it has to provide those options to the JVM, so while you could open an Issue to have that variable added when launching to make Tomcat's native library loadable, I'm not sure there's a simple way to support you further tinkering with that.
